# Why does this method call fail? (Generics & wildcards)

Tags: java, generics, extends

I am getting the below error:

```
'call(ContainsMonitor)' cannot invoke 'call(? extends webscout.Monitor)' in 'WebScoutCallable'
```

Monitor.java

```
WebScoutCallable<? extends Monitor> handler;

public setCallable(WebScoutCallable<? extends Monitor> callable) {
     this.handler = callable;
}
```

WebScoutCallable.java

```
public interface WebScoutCallable<T extends Monitor> {
     public void call(T caller);
}
```

ContainsMonitor.java

```
public class ContainsMonitor extends Monitor {
     public void handleDocument() {
          handler.call(this);
     }
}
```

I'll freely admit that I'm new to generics and still quite new to Java itself. I find the error message confusing as it looks like it should work (method declaration expects a Monitor or subclass, I'm passing in a subclass). Any help (+explanation) would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a wildcard in the type parameter of your `handler` variable.  The compiler doesn't know what the exact type of this type parameter is, only that it's either `Monitor` or a subclass.

The `call` method takes a `T`, which is matched on the wildcard.  But there is no guarantee that the wildcard type is a `ContainsMonitor`.  It could be a `Monitor`, or it could be `MonitorSubtypeThatDoesntExistYet`.  Because the compiler doesn't know the actual type, it cannot allow you to pass anything except `null`, because with any non-`null` argument, it can't guarantee type safety.

You can get around this by removing the wildcard, and replacing that concept with a type parameter on the `Monitor` class.

```
class Monitor<T extends Monitor<T>>
{
    WebScoutCallable<T> handler;

    public void setCallable(WebScoutCallable<T> callable) {
         this.handler = callable;
    }
}
```

The interface `WebScoutCallable` changes a little in response:

```
interface WebScoutCallable<T extends Monitor<T>> {
    public void call(T caller);
}
```

The subclass feeds its own name as the type argument when extending `Monitor`.

```
class ContainsMonitor extends Monitor<ContainsMonitor> {
     public void handleDocument() {
          handler.call(this);
     }
}
```

Now, `T` will be a known type, and `ContainsMonitor` defines it to be itself, so it's now legal for it to pass itself to `call`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I thought there might be a less verbose solution but this makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

`? extends Monitor` means: a specific subclass of Monitor, but we don't know which one. So it may be a `ContainsMonitor` or not and `handler` may or may not be able to accept a `ContainsMonitor`. The compiler can't decide and shows an error.

One way to solve your problem is to use specific types, for example:

```
class Monitor<T extends Monitor<T>> {
  WebScoutCallable<T> handler;

  public setCallable(WebScoutCallable<T> callable) {
    this.handler = callable;
  }
}

class ContainsMonitor extends Monitor<ContainsMonitor> {
  public void handleDocument() {
    handler.call(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Wish I could mark two solutions as correct!